# How to extract an object within a JSON object in PHP and assign it the right index

Tags: php, json

I have the following PHP code (I'll post the important part of it):

```
 // objID
 $objects->objID = generateRandomID();

 $objects->pointer = array('type'=>'__pointer','objID'=>'dgFg45dG','className'=>'Users');

$jsonStr = file_get_contents($className.'.json'); // This calls a Users.json file stored in my server
$jsonObjs = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

            ...

$jsonStr = file_get_contents($className.'.json'); // This calls a Users.json file stored in my server
$jsonObjs = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

array_push($jsonObjs, $objects);

// Encode the array back into a JSON string and save it.
$jsonData = json_encode($jsonObjs);
file_put_contents($className.'.json', $jsonData);
// echo JSON data
echo $jsonData;


    // ISSUE HERE :(
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents($className.'.json');
    // Decode the JSON string into a PHP array.
    $jsonObjs = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

    foreach($jsonObjs as $i=>$obj) {
        print_r('<br><br>'.$i.'-- ');
        echo 
            $obj['objID'].', <br>'
            .$obj['pointer']["$i"]['objID']. ', '
            .$obj['pointer']["$i"]['type']. ', '
            .$obj['pointer']["$i"]['className']. '<br><br>'
        ;               
    }
    // ./ ISSUE
```

The code above creates a new JSON object into my own `Users.json` file.
So, when I call this PHP file with a URL string in my browser, just as a test, and I refresh the page a few times, I get the following echo:

```
0-- VUDjCZX8QX, , , 

1-- 1uWH17OoJP, , , 

[{"objID":"VUDjCZX8QX","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"mark","createdOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:49","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:49","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"1uWH17OoJP","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"mark","createdOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:51","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:51","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"RkubyQPvqR","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"mark","createdOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:54","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:54","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]}]
```

So, what I need to fix is basically the following:

1. What's the right code to properly get the list of items of the
   "pointer" object that's inside each object of my `Users.json` file?
2. I try to track the index of my `foreach` loop, but it doesn't work properly as you can see by the `echo` posted above when I first execute my PHP code, I get the JSON string of my 1st object, I don't get any print_r(). Then, when I refresh the page a 2nd time, I get the print of the `objID` string of my 1st object, and again, if I refresh the page a 3rd time, I get the `objID` of my 2nd object, while there are 3 objects stored in my json file. And so on, in other words, I never get the first object's print info.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `$i` as a string, not as a variable. Use double quotes (`"`) or remove single quotes (`'`) to pass as a variable. This will solve your issue, pointer objects not printing properly.

`$obj['pointer'][$i]['objID']`

**Update**

```
[{"objID":"VUDjCZX8QX","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"mark","createdOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:49","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:49","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"1uWH17OoJP","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"mark","createdOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:51","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:51","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"RkubyQPvqR","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"mark","createdOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:54","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 05:36:54","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]}]
```

According to above JSON string, you don't need specify `$i`.

`$obj['pointer']['objID']` should work, since it is associate array.

Comment: no, sorry, it prints the same results, I've even tried with $obj['pointer'][$i]['objID'], no positive results :(

Comment: @xscoder I have updated the answer. Please try without `$i`.

Comment: thanks so much, you're right, now it works, I've also edited my answer in order to fix the index print by moving the code after the echo $jsonData

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @saumini-navaratnam, I have to use the following `foreach`:

```
foreach($jsonObjs as $i=>$obj) {
   print_r('<br><br>'.$i.'-- ');
   echo 
       $obj['objID'].', '
       .$obj['pointer']['objID']. ', '
       .$obj['pointer']['type']. ', '
       .$obj['pointer']['className']. '<br><br>'
   ;               
}
```

In this way, I can properly get the objects of this object:

```
{"pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"}
```

In fact, here's the echo I get:

```
 [
{"objID":"pkO8NesS5S","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"bobby","createdOn":"2018-09-17 07:03:27","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 07:03:27","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]},
{"objID":"rdwJl20krC","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"bobby","createdOn":"2018-09-17 07:03:31","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 07:03:31","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]},
{"objID":"3WspzmuwMK","pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"dgFg45dG","className":"Users"},"string":"bobby","createdOn":"2018-09-17 07:07:39","updatedOn":"2018-09-17 07:07:39","number":111,"boolean":true,"array":["john","sarah"]}
]

0-- pkO8NesS5S, dgFg45dG, __pointer, Users


1-- rdwJl20krC, dgFg45dG, __pointer, Users


2-- 3WspzmuwMK, dgFg45dG, __pointer, Users
```